General question about aggregation of identical households as a representative one
When I was taking a first-year Macroeconomics class, the Professor always mentioned that "The economy has identical households with a measure of 1". I don't really how to aggregate all the households as a representative.
For example, suppose there are uncountably infinite many households in the economy:
Label $i\in [0,1]$, the individual capital level is $k$ and total capital in the economy is $K$.
Then we have:
$\int_{0}^{1} k(i)\ di = K$, by identity of all the households, then we have $\int_{0}^{1} k\ di = K$, which implies $k(i) = k = K, \forall i \in [0,1]$.
The economy meaning is that individual capital alway equal to the total number of capital, which is not realistic.
I wonder does this mean that the aggregation I learnt is mathematically wrong?
(I asked the professor this question several times and this guy just dodged everytime :(
Thanks so much in advance for any suggestions!
EDIT: I just realized the meaning of "integral" is "average" rather than "summation", so now the question is: is that true for this economy, the total amount of capital is always +$\infty$?

As a mathematical fact, $\int_0^1 K~\mathrm di =K$ is perfectly fine. The way I would read this would be that every agent owns the average amount; the integral gives a population average. This works equally well if you have $n$ households, and each has a weight of $1/n$. Then, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/n~K=K$. So, you might think of the integral representing that each individual has infinitesimal weight and owns an infinitesimal share of the total capital.

Hi, thanks for the answer. About your answer, if K means "average amount" of capital, then how do you calculate the "total amount" of capital in the whole economy? Does that mean the "total amount" is infinity?

Do you have a specific context? Subtleties come in when one looks at population growth, otherwise you can simply treat everything as "per capita."
